# Calculating stats across 1000 arrays

Tags: python, numpy, arrays

I am writing a python module that needs to calculate the mean and standard deviation of pixel values across 1000+ arrays (identical dimensions).

I am looking for the fastest way to do this.

Currently I am looping through the arrays and using numpy.dstack to stack the 1000 arrays into a rather large 3d array...and then will calculate the mean across the 3rd(?) dimension.  Each array has shape (5000,4000).

This approach is taking quite a long time!

Would anyone be able to advise on a more efficient method of approaching this problem?

Comment: Any chance you could show us some code?

Comment: Why dstack them?  Why not just calculate the stats on each on in a loop?

Comment: @mgilson: for-loops in python are slow, if he uses the axis keyword, he can push the for-loops down to numpy (C), which is much faster

Comment: @usethedeathstar -- they might be slow, but dstack isn't going to be particularly fast either.  I don't know the exact details, but I wouldn't be surprised if dstack is trying to find a contiguous chunk of memory big enough to hold all those arrays.  There's no point trying to remove an outer for-loop.  For all intents and purposes, an outer for loop is always free -- It's nested for loops that you need to worry about.

Comment: @mgilson - You're quite correct -- `dstack` _has_ to find contiguous memory big enough to hold all of the 2D arrays.  Numpy arrays have to be described by strides and offsets, so it has to make a new 3D array to hold things (actually, `dstack` always makes a copy, regardless).  If you don't have enough ram for both the 2D arrays and the 3D array, your system will start swapping (slow!).  Another option would be to pre-allocate the 3D array and load each 2D array into it, rather than storing all the 2D arrays in ram and then `dstack`ing them. Calculating stats in a loop would be faster, though.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could calculate `mean` and `std` in a cumulative way something like this (untested):

```
im_size = (5000,4000)

cum_sum = np.zeros(im_size)
cum_sum_of_squares = np.zeros(im_size)
n = 0

for filename in filenames:
    image = read_your_image(filename)
    cum_sum += image
    cum_sum_of_squares += image**2
    n += 1

mean_image = cum_sum / n
std_image = np.sqrt(cum_sum_of_squares / n - (mean_image)**2)
```

This is probably limited by how fast you can read images from disk. It is not limited by memory, since you only have one image in memory at a time. The calculation of `std` in this way might suffer from numerical problems, since you might be subtracting two large numbers. If that is a problem you have to loop over the files twice, first to calculate the mean and then accumulate `(image - mean_image)**2` in the second pass.

Answer (score 1):

preallocate and fill.  This reduced my runtime form about 1000 seconds to 20 seconds

```
data_stack = numpy.empty((321, 720, 1000), dtype=numpy.float32)
for index in range(len(data)):
  data_stack[0:321,0:720,index] = data[index]
```

I was doing something similar.  dstack is not a good solution to this problem.  A colleague reminded me of the dynamic array problem and amortized analysis.  http://anh.cs.luc.edu/363/notes/06A_Amortizing.html

When you want to expand a dynamic array, you need to allocate a new array that can hold the original data and the new data.  You then copy the old array into the new array and the new data into the new array.  That is an expensive operation.

Suppose you have an array of size 10 and you want to add 2 items to it one at a time.  To add the first item you need to expand the array to size 11 and copy in 11 items (original 10 + 1 new item).  To add the second item you need to expand the array to size 12 and copy in 12 items.  If you knew ahead of time that you were adding 2 items you could have resized the array to 12 to start with and only copied 12 items instead of a total of 23.  It turns out that doubling the size of the array every time you run out of space is a much more efficient solution.

How this applies here: dstack doesn't double the size of the ndarray, it's meant to only allocate as much memory as needed.  So each time you call dstack you are copying all of the data you have in your ndarray into a new ndarray with space for the new data.  Notice that the time to dstack increases with each call.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drastically reduce the computation time may opt for solution for multi threading. There are several libraries for python like [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing).